# Getting HTML of parent node including childs html and printing it out

Tags: php

For example in my HTML I have "img" tags.
I want to pack them into "a" tags

If I do this one time everything is ok. But next time the tag which is already packed, packs again and it's bad. What I want is to understand is the "img" already packed into "a" or not.

for this I can use following...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

?????

}
```

So I will get "img" tags by this. Now How to get parent node of the "img" and check if it is "a"?

Comment: maybe get the 'a' and see if it contains an image

Comment: This thing must be working in article editor, and I have images there which must be covered with "a" tags. So I must check "img" tags first.

Comment: please revert your edit to this question, otherwise your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321262/how-to-pass-data-from-domdocument-to-regexp) is likely to be closed as a duplicate of this one. Your question as it was before your edit received good answers, so changing it is not a good idea/recommended.

Comment: You are right , I've marked 2 anwers as solutions and let's close this question cause I've started new differenet questions to continue working on this problem.

Comment: Close them both I've strated different one. This questions are answered and are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?????` would be:

```
if ($img->parentNode->tagName == "a") { ... }
```

Comment: now another problem , your code works and I use it as follows > if ($img->parentNode->tagName != "a") {
but how give preg_match_all this object ? I mean if I give $img straight it cannot work with it, even echo $img gives nothing

Comment: Instead of using that `regex`, I suggest you to use `$img->getAttribute("src")` and you will have the image source.

Comment: The thing is I want to use regex and I want to have in php variable the whole "img" tag. I want exactly this because of the next steps. Can you help me with data transfer to regex ? I want the whole img tag to be transfered

Comment: Well, I noticed you changed the title of the question. If you want to get a node value you can use `$node->nodeValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some code like this in the body of your `foreach` loop...

```
if ($img->parentNode->tagName == 'a') {
   continue;
}
```

Make sure it is the first thing, obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

The following might work

```
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    if(!$img.packed) {
       .... //packing code
       $img.packed = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to determine if the parent node of the `img` tag is an `a` tag.  For your answer to be relevant to the problem, you would need to provide the code needed to determine the value of `$img.packed` [sic; PHP syntax uses `->`, not `.` for indirection].

Comment: @Phoenix: didn't noticed it was PHP, I think it was tagged under javascript by then and I acted on that. Too bad I didnt noticed the syntax.