# How to pass data from DOMDocument to regexp?

Tags: php

Using the following code I get "img" tags from some html and check them if they are covered with "a" tags. Later if current "img" tag is not part of the "a" ( hyperlink ) I want to do cover this img tag into "a" tag adding hyperlinks start ending tag plus setting to target. For this I want the whole "img" tags html to work with.

Question is how can I transfer "img" tags html into regexp. I need some php variable in regexp to work with the place is marked with ??? signs.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

if ($img->parentNode->tagName != "a") {

preg_match_all("|<img(.*)\/>|U", ??? , $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

                                      }
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use regex for this. You already have a DOM, so use it:

```
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
  $container = $img->parentNode;

  if ($container->tagName != "a") { 
    $a = $doc->createElement("a");
    $a->appendChild( $img->cloneNode(true) );
    $container->replaceChild($a, $img);
  }
}
```

see documentation on

- [`DOMDocument::createElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)
- [`DOMNode::appendChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php)
- [`DOMNode::cloneNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php)
- [`DOMNode::replaceChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php)

Comment: ok but I have parameters to set in that "a". I mean this > `<img src="sources/public/users/qqqqqq/articles/2011-06-11/7/img/500.JPG" alt="" width="500" height="360">` must be changed to this >`a href="sources/public/users/qqqqqq/articles/2011-06-11/7/img/500.JPG"  target="_blank"><img src="sources/public/users/qqqqqq/articles/2011-06-11/7/mini/500.JPG" alt="500.JPG" ></a>`

Comment: See [`DOMElement::setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) and [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php). I'm sure you will figure this out.